# how to put in a list the values of multiple command line arguments

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I have a cli `build.py` I call it `build.py -t -c -f`
When I parse the command line arguments, Is there a built in way to get a list of

```
['t' = true,'c'=true,'f'=true,'s'=false]
```

Below are the definitions, not sure what to change in the `dest` (that addition of `[..]` is not working. Just to show what I try to achieve.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter

parser = ArgumentParser(description=program_license, formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument("-s","--stored_proc", dest="build_what['s']", action="store_true", help="build all stored procedures, or the folder/*.sql specified")
parser.add_argument("-t","--triggers", dest="build_what['t']", action="store_true", help="build all triggers, or the folder/*.sql specified")
parser.add_argument("-f","--functions", dest="build_what['f']", action="store_true", help="build all functions, or the folder/*.sql specified")
parser.add_argument("-c","--scripts", dest="build_what['c']", action="store_true", help="run all scripts, or the folder/*.sql specified")
```

Comment: do you use `argparse`?

Comment: modified I am using ArgumentParser, from argparse import ArgumentParser
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter

Comment: `['t' = true,'c'=true,'f'=true,'s'=false]` is not a Python list. You mean a dictionary (`{'t':true,'c':true,'f':true,'s':false}`)?

Comment: well...does not really matter to me for this specific task wether it is a list or dictionary I think

Comment: Use `dest='s'` if you want the short name in the `Namespace`.  Without the `dest` value it will use `'stored_proc'`.

Comment: thanks, I am aware of this, I try to see if there is a built in way to make the dest a dictionary instead of a scalar

Answer (score 0):

The `parse_args` method of argument parsers returns a [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace). You can access your values directly as properties there:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.stored_proc # or `args.s` if you set `dest` to `'s'`
```

If you need dictionary access (for whatever reason), you can use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to convert it:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['-s', '-f'])
Namespace(c=False, f=True, s=True, t=False)
>>> vars(_)
{'f': True, 'c': False, 't': False, 's': True}
```

Note, that that dictionary will contain *all* registered arguments, and not only those four. So if you need a dictionary with exactly those four values, it’s probably better to create it explicitely:

```
{'f': args.f, 'c': args.c, 't': args.t, 's': args.s}
```